# QuartzScheduler Trigger Issue

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Am facing a Problem with QuartzScheduler  trigger defination.

Thu Feb 28 16:27:30 IST 2019   : Start time

0/20 0 0 ? * * *   Cron Expression

Thu Feb 28 16:29:30 IST 2019  End Time

Trigger schedulerAdderTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(triggerkey)               .startAt(schedulerdata.getScheduleStartDate())             .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(schedulerdata.getChroneExpression())).endAt(schedulerdata.getScheduleEndDate())    .usingJobData(jobDataMap).build();

Am getting the Below Error,What might be the reason.

Error :

org.quartz.SchedulerException: Based on configured schedule, the given trigger 'DEFAULT.1010001_50' will never fire.
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:882)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:249)
    at com.naresh.sample.job.ReportDashboardDataLoader.addJobToScheduler(ReportDashboardDataLoader.java:128)
    at com.naresh.sample.job.ReportDashboardDataLoader.addToScheduler(ReportDashboardDataLoader.java:81)
    at com.naresh.sample.job.ReportDashboardDataLoader.execute(ReportDashboardDataLoader.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

Also I tried to change the granularity to minute level( 0 0/1 0 ? * * *) in that case nothings running.

Please help me in understanding the problem.

regards,

Naresh

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Problem is my side.Cron Expression which I used is wrong. I just over looked it.

Thanks,
Naresh